# Win32 opengl Window creation

Tags: winapi, opengl, window

What is the best way to set up a window in win32 that has OpenGl(and glsl if the needs extra code to work) integrated into it?

I have done some research and found numerous ways of accomplishing this task i was wondering what the best way is or what way you like the most if the best way doesn't have an answer.

I have looked at nehe`s design and also the one supplied by the OpenGl super bible which both have completely different ways of accomplishing it (also the super bibles one gives me errors :().

any help would be appreciated including tutorials etc.

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All your "different ways" aren't so different.  You have to:

- create your window (in the usual Win32 way, with `RegisterClass(Ex)` and `CreateWindow(Ex)`)
- create a GDI device context corresponding to your window (`GetDC`)
- pick a pixel format which is supported by the display (optional `DescribePixelFormat`, then `ChoosePixelFormat`)
- create your OpenGL context (`wglCreateContext`)
- (optional, but required to use GLSL) link OpenGL extension functions (GLee or GLEW helpers, or `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` then `wglGetProcAddress`)
- (optional) create an OpenGL 3.x context, free the compatibility context (`wglCreateContextAttribs`)
- make the context active (`wglMakeCurrent`)
- start using OpenGL (set up shader programs, load textures, draw stuff, etc.)

---

An excerpt of code showing these steps in action (not suitable for copy+paste, a bunch of RAII wrappers are used):

```
bool Context::attach( HWND hwnd )
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = { sizeof(pfd), 1 };
    if (!m_dc) {
        scoped_window_hdc(hwnd).swap(m_dc);

        pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
        pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
        pfd.cColorBits = 32;
        pfd.cAlphaBits = 8;
        pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
        auto format_index = ::ChoosePixelFormat(m_dc.get(), &pfd);
        if (!format_index)
            return false;

        if (!::SetPixelFormat(m_dc.get(), format_index, &pfd))
            return false;
    }

    auto active_format_index = ::GetPixelFormat(m_dc.get());
    if (!active_format_index)
        return false;

    if (!::DescribePixelFormat(m_dc.get(), active_format_index, sizeof pfd, &pfd))
        return false;

    if ((pfd.dwFlags & PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL) != PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL)
        return false;

    m_render_thread = ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, &RenderThreadProc, this, 0, NULL);
    return m_render_thread != NULL;
}

DWORD WINAPI Context::RenderThreadProc( LPVOID param )
{
    Context* const ctx = static_cast<Context*>(param);
    HDC dc = ctx->m_dc.get();

    SIZE canvas_size;
    ctx->m_dc.check_resize(&canvas_size);

    scoped_hglrc glrc(wglCreateContext(dc));

    if (!glrc)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    if (!glrc.make_current(dc))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    if (ctx->m_major_version > 2 && GLEE_WGL_ARB_create_context) {
        int const create_attribs[] = {
            WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, ctx->m_major_version,
            WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, ctx->m_minor_version,
            0
        };
        scoped_hglrc advrc(wglCreateContextAttribsARB(dc, 0, create_attribs));

        if (advrc) {
            if (!advrc.make_current(dc))
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            advrc.swap(glrc);
        }
    }

    {
        const char* ver = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glGetString(GL_VERSION));
        if (ver) {
            OutputDebugStringA("GL_VERSION = \"");
            OutputDebugStringA(ver);
            OutputDebugStringA("\"\n");
        }
    }

    glDisable(GL_DITHER);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    if (GLEE_WGL_EXT_swap_control)
        wglSwapIntervalEXT(1);

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    while (!::InterlockedExchange(&ctx->m_stop_render, 0)) {
        ctx->process_queued_tasks();

        if (ctx->m_dc.check_resize(&canvas_size)) {
            glViewport(0, 0, canvas_size.cx, canvas_size.cy);
            ctx->process_on_resize();
        }
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        ctx->process_on_render();

        BOOL swapped = ::SwapBuffers(dc);
        if (!swapped)
            std::cout << "::SwapBuffers failure, GetLastError() returns " << std::hex << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    ctx->m_program_db.clear();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It also doesn't cover window creation, it enables OpenGL on an existing window.

Comment: great thanks for the help for the very basic setup is this http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=01 a good setup? and then all i need to do is add 3.x and shader support?

Comment: Yeah, that's good as far as context creation is concerned.  I learned a lot from NeHe tutorials when I was getting started.

Comment: great :D now i will attempt to add the extra stuff.

Comment: If you want, I can show some code from a personal project.  It's not standalone, and it uses GLee for extension access, but it provides a concrete example of the above steps.

Comment: i have a quick question about the above code.. ::DescribePixelFormat what do the double colons do?

Comment: @Phantasm: It's the scope resolution operator -- you're probably used to seeing it after a class name or namespace name (eg `std::cout`).  When there's no name in front, it looks in the global namespace (and only there, unlike an unqualified name).

Answer (score 6):

This pretty much did it for me: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_%28win32%29/13001/

**EDIT:** Related code:

```
/*
 *      This Code Was Created By Jeff Molofee 2000
 *      A HUGE Thanks To Fredric Echols For Cleaning Up
 *      And Optimizing This Code, Making It More Flexible!
 *      If You've Found This Code Useful, Please Let Me Know.
 *      Visit My Site At nehe.gamedev.net
 */

#include <windows.h>        // Header File For Windows
#include <gl\gl.h>          // Header File For The OpenGL32 Library
#include <gl\glu.h>         // Header File For The GLu32 Library
#include <gl\glaux.h>       // Header File For The Glaux Library

HDC         hDC=NULL;       // Private GDI Device Context
HGLRC       hRC=NULL;       // Permanent Rendering Context
HWND        hWnd=NULL;      // Holds Our Window Handle
HINSTANCE   hInstance;      // Holds The Instance Of The Application

bool    keys[256];          // Array Used For The Keyboard Routine
bool    active=TRUE;        // Window Active Flag Set To TRUE By Default
bool    fullscreen=TRUE;    // Fullscreen Flag Set To Fullscreen Mode By Default

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);   // Declaration For WndProc

GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei width, GLsizei height)     // Resize And Initialize The GL Window
{
    if (height==0)                                      // Prevent A Divide By Zero By
    {
        height=1;                                       // Making Height Equal One
    }

    glViewport(0,0,width,height);                       // Reset The Current Viewport

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                        // Select The Projection Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Projection Matrix

    // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,0.1f,100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                         // Select The Modelview Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Modelview Matrix
}

int InitGL(GLvoid)                                      // All Setup For OpenGL Goes Here
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            // Enable Smooth Shading
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);               // Black Background
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                                 // Depth Buffer Setup
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            // Enables Depth Testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                             // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    return TRUE;                                        // Initialization Went OK
}

int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)                                 // Here's Where We Do All The Drawing
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
    glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Current Modelview Matrix
    return TRUE;                                        // Everything Went OK
}

GLvoid KillGLWindow(GLvoid)                             // Properly Kill The Window
{
    if (fullscreen)                                     // Are We In Fullscreen Mode?
    {
        ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL,0);                  // If So Switch Back To The Desktop
        ShowCursor(TRUE);                               // Show Mouse Pointer
    }

    if (hRC)                                            // Do We Have A Rendering Context?
    {
        if (!wglMakeCurrent(NULL,NULL))                 // Are We Able To Release The DC And RC Contexts?
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,"Release Of DC And RC Failed.","SHUTDOWN ERROR",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }

        if (!wglDeleteContext(hRC))                     // Are We Able To Delete The RC?
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,"Release Rendering Context Failed.","SHUTDOWN ERROR",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        hRC=NULL;                                       // Set RC To NULL
    }

    if (hDC && !ReleaseDC(hWnd,hDC))                    // Are We Able To Release The DC
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Release Device Context Failed.","SHUTDOWN ERROR",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        hDC=NULL;                                       // Set DC To NULL
    }

    if (hWnd && !DestroyWindow(hWnd))                   // Are We Able To Destroy The Window?
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Could Not Release hWnd.","SHUTDOWN ERROR",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        hWnd=NULL;                                      // Set hWnd To NULL
    }

    if (!UnregisterClass("OpenGL",hInstance))           // Are We Able To Unregister Class
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Could Not Unregister Class.","SHUTDOWN ERROR",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        hInstance=NULL;                                 // Set hInstance To NULL
    }
}

/*  This Code Creates Our OpenGL Window.  Parameters Are:                   *
 *  title           - Title To Appear At The Top Of The Window              *
 *  width           - Width Of The GL Window Or Fullscreen Mode             *
 *  height          - Height Of The GL Window Or Fullscreen Mode            *
 *  bits            - Number Of Bits To Use For Color (8/16/24/32)          *
 *  fullscreenflag  - Use Fullscreen Mode (TRUE) Or Windowed Mode (FALSE)   */

BOOL CreateGLWindow(char* title, int width, int height, int bits, bool fullscreenflag)
{
    GLuint      PixelFormat;            // Holds The Results After Searching For A Match
    WNDCLASS    wc;                     // Windows Class Structure
    DWORD       dwExStyle;              // Window Extended Style
    DWORD       dwStyle;                // Window Style
    RECT        WindowRect;             // Grabs Rectangle Upper Left / Lower Right Values
    WindowRect.left=(long)0;            // Set Left Value To 0
    WindowRect.right=(long)width;       // Set Right Value To Requested Width
    WindowRect.top=(long)0;             // Set Top Value To 0
    WindowRect.bottom=(long)height;     // Set Bottom Value To Requested Height

    fullscreen=fullscreenflag;          // Set The Global Fullscreen Flag

    hInstance           = GetModuleHandle(NULL);                // Grab An Instance For Our Window
    wc.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;   // Redraw On Size, And Own DC For Window.
    wc.lpfnWndProc      = (WNDPROC) WndProc;                    // WndProc Handles Messages
    wc.cbClsExtra       = 0;                                    // No Extra Window Data
    wc.cbWndExtra       = 0;                                    // No Extra Window Data
    wc.hInstance        = hInstance;                            // Set The Instance
    wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);          // Load The Default Icon
    wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);          // Load The Arrow Pointer
    wc.hbrBackground    = NULL;                                 // No Background Required For GL
    wc.lpszMenuName     = NULL;                                 // We Don't Want A Menu
    wc.lpszClassName    = "OpenGL";                             // Set The Class Name

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))                                    // Attempt To Register The Window Class
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Failed To Register The Window Class.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                                           // Return FALSE
    }

    if (fullscreen)                                             // Attempt Fullscreen Mode?
    {
        DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;                               // Device Mode
        memset(&dmScreenSettings,0,sizeof(dmScreenSettings));   // Makes Sure Memory's Cleared
        dmScreenSettings.dmSize=sizeof(dmScreenSettings);       // Size Of The Devmode Structure
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth    = width;                // Selected Screen Width
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight   = height;               // Selected Screen Height
        dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel   = bits;                 // Selected Bits Per Pixel
        dmScreenSettings.dmFields=DM_BITSPERPEL|DM_PELSWIDTH|DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        // Try To Set Selected Mode And Get Results.  NOTE: CDS_FULLSCREEN Gets Rid Of Start Bar.
        if (ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings,CDS_FULLSCREEN)!=DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
        {
            // If The Mode Fails, Offer Two Options.  Quit Or Use Windowed Mode.
            if (MessageBox(NULL,"The Requested Fullscreen Mode Is Not Supported By\nYour Video Card. Use Windowed Mode Instead?","NeHe GL",MB_YESNO|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION)==IDYES)
            {
                fullscreen=FALSE;       // Windowed Mode Selected.  Fullscreen = FALSE
            }
            else
            {
                // Pop Up A Message Box Letting User Know The Program Is Closing.
                MessageBox(NULL,"Program Will Now Close.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
                return FALSE;                                   // Return FALSE
            }
        }
    }

    if (fullscreen)                                             // Are We Still In Fullscreen Mode?
    {
        dwExStyle=WS_EX_APPWINDOW;                              // Window Extended Style
        dwStyle=WS_POPUP;                                       // Windows Style
        ShowCursor(FALSE);                                      // Hide Mouse Pointer
    }
    else
    {
        dwExStyle=WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;           // Window Extended Style
        dwStyle=WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;                            // Windows Style
    }

    AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);     // Adjust Window To True Requested Size

    // Create The Window
    if (!(hWnd=CreateWindowEx(  dwExStyle,                          // Extended Style For The Window
                                "OpenGL",                           // Class Name
                                title,                              // Window Title
                                dwStyle |                           // Defined Window Style
                                WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |                   // Required Window Style
                                WS_CLIPCHILDREN,                    // Required Window Style
                                0, 0,                               // Window Position
                                WindowRect.right-WindowRect.left,   // Calculate Window Width
                                WindowRect.bottom-WindowRect.top,   // Calculate Window Height
                                NULL,                               // No Parent Window
                                NULL,                               // No Menu
                                hInstance,                          // Instance
                                NULL)))                             // Dont Pass Anything To WM_CREATE
    {
        KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL,"Window Creation Error.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                               // Return FALSE
    }

    static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=              // pfd Tells Windows How We Want Things To Be
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),              // Size Of This Pixel Format Descriptor
        1,                                          // Version Number
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |                        // Format Must Support Window
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |                        // Format Must Support OpenGL
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                           // Must Support Double Buffering
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                              // Request An RGBA Format
        bits,                                       // Select Our Color Depth
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                           // Color Bits Ignored
        0,                                          // No Alpha Buffer
        0,                                          // Shift Bit Ignored
        0,                                          // No Accumulation Buffer
        0, 0, 0, 0,                                 // Accumulation Bits Ignored
        16,                                         // 16Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)  
        0,                                          // No Stencil Buffer
        0,                                          // No Auxiliary Buffer
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                             // Main Drawing Layer
        0,                                          // Reserved
        0, 0, 0                                     // Layer Masks Ignored
    };

    if (!(hDC=GetDC(hWnd)))                         // Did We Get A Device Context?
    {
        KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL,"Can't Create A GL Device Context.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                               // Return FALSE
    }

    if (!(PixelFormat=ChoosePixelFormat(hDC,&pfd))) // Did Windows Find A Matching Pixel Format?
    {
        KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL,"Can't Find A Suitable PixelFormat.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                               // Return FALSE
    }

    if(!SetPixelFormat(hDC,PixelFormat,&pfd))       // Are We Able To Set The Pixel Format?
    {
        KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL,"Can't Set The PixelFormat.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                               // Return FALSE
    }

    if (!(hRC=wglCreateContext(hDC)))               // Are We Able To Get A Rendering Context?
    {
        KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL,"Can't Create A GL Rendering Context.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                               // Return FALSE
    }

    if(!wglMakeCurrent(hDC,hRC))                    // Try To Activate The Rendering Context
    {
        KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL,"Can't Activate The GL Rendering Context.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                               // Return FALSE
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOW);                       // Show The Window
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);                      // Slightly Higher Priority
    SetFocus(hWnd);                                 // Sets Keyboard Focus To The Window
    ReSizeGLScene(width, height);                   // Set Up Our Perspective GL Screen

    if (!InitGL())                                  // Initialize Our Newly Created GL Window
    {
        KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL,"Initialization Failed.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                               // Return FALSE
    }

    return TRUE;                                    // Success
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(   HWND    hWnd,           // Handle For This Window
                            UINT    uMsg,           // Message For This Window
                            WPARAM  wParam,         // Additional Message Information
                            LPARAM  lParam)         // Additional Message Information
{
    switch (uMsg)                                   // Check For Windows Messages
    {
        case WM_ACTIVATE:                           // Watch For Window Activate Message
        {
            if (!HIWORD(wParam))                    // Check Minimization State
            {
                active=TRUE;                        // Program Is Active
            }
            else
            {
                active=FALSE;                       // Program Is No Longer Active
            }

            return 0;                               // Return To The Message Loop
        }

        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:                         // Intercept System Commands
        {
            switch (wParam)                         // Check System Calls
            {
                case SC_SCREENSAVE:                 // Screensaver Trying To Start?
                case SC_MONITORPOWER:               // Monitor Trying To Enter Powersave?
                return 0;                           // Prevent From Happening
            }
            break;                                  // Exit
        }

        case WM_CLOSE:                              // Did We Receive A Close Message?
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);                     // Send A Quit Message
            return 0;                               // Jump Back
        }

        case WM_KEYDOWN:                            // Is A Key Being Held Down?
        {
            keys[wParam] = TRUE;                    // If So, Mark It As TRUE
            return 0;                               // Jump Back
        }

        case WM_KEYUP:                              // Has A Key Been Released?
        {
            keys[wParam] = FALSE;                   // If So, Mark It As FALSE
            return 0;                               // Jump Back
        }

        case WM_SIZE:                               // Resize The OpenGL Window
        {
            ReSizeGLScene(LOWORD(lParam),HIWORD(lParam));  // LoWord=Width, HiWord=Height
            return 0;                               // Jump Back
        }
    }

    // Pass All Unhandled Messages To DefWindowProc
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE   hInstance,          // Instance
                    HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,      // Previous Instance
                    LPSTR       lpCmdLine,          // Command Line Parameters
                    int         nCmdShow)           // Window Show State
{
    MSG     msg;                                    // Windows Message Structure
    BOOL    done=FALSE;                             // Bool Variable To Exit Loop

    // Ask The User Which Screen Mode They Prefer
    if (MessageBox(NULL,"Would You Like To Run In Fullscreen Mode?", "Start FullScreen?",MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION)==IDNO)
    {
        fullscreen=FALSE;                           // Windowed Mode
    }

    // Create Our OpenGL Window
    if (!CreateGLWindow("NeHe's OpenGL Framework",640,480,16,fullscreen))
    {
        return 0;                                   // Quit If Window Was Not Created
    }

    while(!done)                                    // Loop That Runs While done=FALSE
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))   // Is There A Message Waiting?
        {
            if (msg.message==WM_QUIT)               // Have We Received A Quit Message?
            {
                done=TRUE;                          // If So done=TRUE
            }
            else                                    // If Not, Deal With Window Messages
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);             // Translate The Message
                DispatchMessage(&msg);              // Dispatch The Message
            }
        }
        else                                        // If There Are No Messages
        {
            // Draw The Scene.  Watch For ESC Key And Quit Messages From DrawGLScene()
            if (active)                             // Program Active?
            {
                if (keys[VK_ESCAPE])                // Was ESC Pressed?
                {
                    done=TRUE;                      // ESC Signalled A Quit
                }
                else                                // Not Time To Quit, Update Screen
                {
                    DrawGLScene();                  // Draw The Scene
                    SwapBuffers(hDC);               // Swap Buffers (Double Buffering)
                }
            }

            if (keys[VK_F1])                        // Is F1 Being Pressed?
            {
                keys[VK_F1]=FALSE;                  // If So Make Key FALSE
                KillGLWindow();                     // Kill Our Current Window
                fullscreen=!fullscreen;             // Toggle Fullscreen / Windowed Mode
                // Recreate Our OpenGL Window
                if (!CreateGLWindow("NeHe's OpenGL Framework",640,480,16,fullscreen))
                {
                    return 0;                       // Quit If Window Was Not Created
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Shutdown
    KillGLWindow();                                 // Kill The Window
    return (msg.wParam);                            // Exit The Program
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really, really want to do it yourself, you can still have a look at how GLFW does it. In its source directory, you have a win32-specific directory, in which you have a windowing-specic .c file. You should find everything you need in this file.

[This page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context) of the OpenGL Wiki could help you, too.

Answer (score -6):

The best way is NOT to do it yourself. OpenGL context creation is a bottomless abyss of complexity. You have lots of tools that can do the dirty work for you, and what's more, it'll work on Linux and Mac too

GLFW, FreeGlut, SDL, SFML are probably the most common.

See [GLFW's user guide](http://www.glfw.org/GLFWUsersGuide27.pdf), for instance, to see how easy these libs make it to create a window :

```
glfwInit();
glfwOpenWindow( 300,300, 0,0,0,0,0,0, GLFW_WINDOW );
// bam, you're done
```

Comment: this answer is off topic...i specifically asked how to accomplish it using the win32 api not some external library. i am aware of the capabilities of external library but i wish to use the win32 api.

Comment: i am attempting to create a game engine from scratch using only opengl and c++, with preferably no library`s...also using a library that deals with windows creation takes a lot of the control away that would be needed for making a game.

Comment: That's more or less what I thought. I wholeheartedly with your "from scratch" approach, I love low level stuff, but honesly, this isn't worth the pain. Learning OpenGL's context creation is a real pain, doing it right is complicated, and most importantly, you won't learn anything (useful) from this. I consider that I wrote a game engine from scratch, but yet I use GLFW and have no moral issue with this. Use your time wisely and learn real OpenGL instead, IMHO.

Comment: i am using the opengl superbible for learning opengl and in this i am also using free glut.but i am also creating a game engine which i will implement the knowledge from the super bible into but use win32 so i have complete control rather then glut which is very restrictive

Comment: Again : 1) You won't learn anything interesting 2) glut *is* restrictive, that's why I gave other suggestions.

Comment: @I Phantasm I So when you want to do it with Win32 API, then there aren't numerous ways to accomplish it, just the Win32 API solution. Look at Ben's answer, that's the way to do it.